# Stuck on login in linux due to font changed to Hindi, Solution?

Tags: linux, authentication, fonts, operating-system, passwords

I got stuck on `login` panel in `linux OS`. Becuase default setting has changed to `hindi`. 
How to solve this problem ?
Unable to reset password `English Character` to `Digits` (Because digits are working properly so I thought to change)
But Unable to do this also because of same reason.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't worry! 
Simple solution is here.
press `power button` and go to login panel
press `win` + `space` button and select `en` as default lanuage.
Now you can login into your system.